# How to prevent the initial page break when calling \chapter inside a tcolorbox

Tags: chapters, tcolorbox

I am trying to put a whole `\chapter` inside of a breakable `tcolorbox`. This results in the box being broken even before the chapter heading and an almost empty page is added. The following MWE shows this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable]
\chapter*{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way how to prevent this initial page break?

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the early breaking is `\clearpage` -- a chapter by default uses `\cleardoublepage` which calls `\clearpage`, so a new page is shipped, leading to premature breaking of the `tcolorbox`.

Preventing this:

Using `before upper={\let\clearpage\relax}` as option leaves the change of `\clearpage` internally to the `tcolorbox` and does not leak outside:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,before upper={\let\clearpage\relax}]
\chapter*{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{tcolorbox}
% Just for testing
\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can locally redefine the `\clearpage` command, that `\chapter` seems to use, in order to prevent it from doing anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mychap}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
        \let\clearpage\relax%
        \chapter*{#1}
    \endgroup%
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable]
\mychap{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

There might be side effects, though; I'm not sure.
Alternatively, redefine `\@makeschapterhead` (it works for the `report` documentclass, so maybe for books too). This is a command that typesets the heading for `\chapter*`. This should be documented in some places.